# ¿Cómo convertir caracteres con Javascript para cargar archivos externos?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito insertar un vídeo dentro del DOM usando la url de los archivos, pero esta url necesita caracteres unicode.

La url la obtengo del a siguiente manera:

```
let link = img[i].parentElement.href;
```

Pero al obtener la url con javascript me arroja esto.

```
https://sitio.com/video-php?v=/%CE%A9/src/hola.webm
```

Si copio y pego la url anterior en el explorador se convierte a esto:

```
https://sitio.com/video-php?v=/Ω/src/hola.webm
```

La manera de insertarlo sería obtener la url del vídeo con javascript y después insertarlo en una etiqueta de vídeo.

```
<video autoplay loop="true" src="URL DEL VIDEO"></video>
```

Mi problema es que si inserto la url sin unicode el vídeo no aparece.

```
// ERROR
<video src="https://sitio.com/video-php?v=/%CE%A9/src/hola.webm"></video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/decodeURI) para devolver la URL original. Pongo un ejemplo de cómo cuando se obtiene el `href` del enlace codifica el símbolo Ω y con `decodeURI()` lo decodifica de nuevo:

```js
var link = document.querySelector("a").href;
var encode = document.getElementById("encode");
encode.innerHTML = link;
var uri = decodeURI(link)
var decode = document.getElementById("decode");
decode.innerHTML = uri;
```

```css
#encode {
  color: red;

}

#decode {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://sitio.com/video-php?v=/Ω/src/hola.webm">Mi enlace</a>
<p>obtengo el href del enlace --> <span id="encode"></span></p>
<p>decodifico la URL obtenida --> <span id="decode"></span></p>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto me ayudó muchísimo para llegar a la solución.